# How do I insert a prefetch instruction in LLVM?

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-ir, prefetch

I have with me the result of a getelementptr instruction, which is the address I need to prefetch from.

Comment: http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#llvm-prefetch-intrinsic      http://marc.info/?l=llvm-dev&m=136561718327032

Comment: I did see this code block before. But I found it pretty hard to follow without any explanation.

Comment: can you post some your current effort and the issue you are getting?

Comment: also prefetch is intrinsic. one more reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985247/llvm-insert-intrinsic-function-cos

Comment: In the code block that you linked first, I'm not able to understand what `IRBuilder<> Builder(MemI);` does exactly. Also, I don't understand what the use of `ConstantInt::get(I32, 3), ConstantInt::get(I32, 1)` is.